# Error in <dislplay:table> tag pagination

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

When I am printing value via iterator value gets printed, when I am using `<display:table>` tag for same purpose I am getting no value to display message.

Working Iterator tag code:

```jsp
<s:iterator value=" #request.hrlist" var="employee" >

<s:property value="Employee_Name" />
<s:property value="password" />

</s:iterator>
```

Display table code:

```jsp
<display:table id="#request.hrlist" name="#request.hrlist"  requestURI="/HrAction.do" pagesize="10" >

<display:column property="Employee_Name" title="TV Show" sortable="true"/>
<display:column property="password" title="User Name" sortable="true"/>


</display:table>
```

How to print value via display table as it provide sortable pagination feature?

Comment: Why I am getting nothing found to display message via display table tag. please help me

Comment: I found that this was due to naming convention in BEAN CLASS, actually variable should be in small to capital (employee_Name) , while my variabl was  Capital to Capital (Employee_Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was due to naming convention in BEAN CLASS, actually variable should be in small to capital (employee_Name) , while my variabl was Capital to Capital (Employee_Name) –